# Always Null data i databaseinitializer in my SQL Server database asp.net core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My database always has null data. I don't know why the database initializer code is not being executed. I have a database that contains a `digitaldocument` table with `fields` which shown in the code. i tried to not assigned a value for id but still not working. Here is my code:

```
  public class DigitalDocument
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; } 
    public List<Tag> Tages { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}


namespace i2ana.Web.DataAccess.Models
{
    public class DatabaseInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

        public DatabaseInitializer(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public async Task SeedAsync()
        {
            await this.context.Database.MigrateAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (!this.context.DigitalDocuments.Any())
            {
                DigitalDocument DigitalDocument1 = new DigitalDocument
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Flower",
                    Location = "Location1",
                    Image = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 },
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.Today,
                    Tages = new List<Tag> { new Tag { Id = 1, Value = "Tag 1" }, new Tag { Id = 1, Value = "Tag 2" } }
                };
                context.DigitalDocuments.Add(DigitalDocument1);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i sugesst you to post your database table to make extra explination,
extra why u assert id ? u could make ie in database auto increment ?

Comment: Seeding is now natively supported in ef-core.

Comment: sorry, i dont understand what you mean

Comment: @Gert meant EF Core 2.1 [Data Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding)

Comment: @IvanStoev so, should i remove the seeding method !

Comment: @BilalMarzouk i was tried to not assert id, but still not fixed !